# How to use aggregate in Laravel Eloquent whereHas query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

My models are set up in the following way:

A `Product` `hasMany` `ProductOption`s and a `ProductOption` `belongsTo` a single `Option`.

I'm trying to query for `Product`s that have at least 2 `ProductOption`s that belong to `Option`s that do not contain the string `Oversized Shipping` in their name.

Here what I have so far:

```
Product::whereHas('productOptions', function($q) {
    $q->whereHas('option', function($q) {
        $q->where('name', 'not like', '%Oversized Shipping%');
    });
})
->get();
```

How can I add the constraint that there must be at least two valid `ProductOption`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `whereHas` method [takes additional arguments just for this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L642):

```
$products = Product::whereHas('productOptions', function ($q) {
    $q->whereHas('option', function ($q) {
        $q->where('name', 'not like', '%Oversized Shipping%');
    });
}, '>=', 2)->get();
```